Analisys Service Error > mismo servidor
Saludos a todos en la comunidad dba, tengo una pregunta es posible tener varias instancias de analisys service corriendo en simultaneo en el mismo servidor en su versión 2019 de SQL, debido a que estoy migrando un servidor que tiene actualmente analisys service SQL SERVER 2014 a SQL SERVER 2019 y solo puedo tener arriba 4 y necesito 6 es posible hacerlo en esta versión.
Adjunto pantalla con el error


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!
